# Simple Select query is running more than 5hours db2

Tags: db2

We have a select query as below . Query to fetch the data is running more than 5 hours.

```
select ColumnA,
ColumnB,
ColumnC,
ColumnD,
ColumnE 
from Table 
where CodeN <> 'Z'
```

Is there any way we can collect stats or any other way to improve performance .. ? 
And in DB2 do we have any table where we can check whether collect stats are collected on the below table..

Comment: Have you tried to read the doc about the `runstats` command?

Comment: If you have large amounts of data, no index on that CodeN column and a slow I/O system, then a disk scan might be slow. But there are many options on how to tune the query, even automatically. Please provide more details

Comment: @MarkBarinstein.. Thanks for the reply.. Can you help me with the document of runstats .. and also is there any way to check if the table collect stats has been collected or no ?

Comment: @data_henrik.. Hi henrik.. We dont have an index defined in the table

Comment: Which OS family are you running DB2 server running on?  The correct answer to your question depends on which edition of DB2 you're using.   DB2 for z/OS, or IBM i, or Linux / Unix / Windows have different implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The [RUNSTATS command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001980.html) collects table & indexes statistics.   Note, that this is a Db2 **command** and not an SQL statement, so you may either run it with Db2 Command Line Processor (CLP) or using relational interface with a special Stored Procedure, which is able to run such commands:
[RUNSTATS command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023587.html).
Statistics is stored in the `SYSSTAT` schema views. Refer to [Road map to the catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html) - `Table 2. Road map to the updatable catalog views`.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows exist in table?
and not equal operator '<>' not indexable predicates